# How to properly format this data for Material Table [dataSource]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular-material

I can get the data from the API to show using `*ngFor='let earning of symbolEarnings.earnings'`>`{{earning.actualEPS}}`Now I'm trying to use the mat-table so it's uniform with the rest of my app.

Now if I use `symbolEarnings` which is an object Object in the [dataSource], I get the error

> Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

Now what I've been doing for the past hours is trying to convert to an array. As reference, this is the data.

```
{"symbol":"AAPL","earnings":
[
{"actualEPS":2.91, "EPSReportDate":"2018-11-01"},
{"actualEPS":2.34,"EPSReportDate":"2018-07-31"}
]}
```

So I use this to get symbolEarnings

```
    getEarning(): void {
        const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
        this.svc.getEarningById(id).subscribe(data => {
          this.symbolEarnings = data;
```

which works fine when I do `'let x of symbolEarnings.earnings' {{x.actualEPS]]`

The data is currently an object Object, so I get the error highlighted above.

I try to convert the earnings part into an array to no avail.
`this.test = this.symbolEarnings.earnings;` or `this.testArray = Object.keys(this.test).map(i => this.test[i]);`

The interesting thing is that `testArray` works for `[dataSource]` but I need to do `*ngFor='let y of testArray' [dataSource]="testArray"` to get the column then use `<td mat-cell>{{y.actualEPS}}</td>` which produces result but it's repeating on multiple table.

```
For example, EPS: 2, 2, 2 EPS: 3, 3, 3 EPS: 4, 4, 4 rather than EPS: 2, 3, 4
```

So I kinda sorta got it kinda working, but I clearly need some help with this. Let me know if you have any questions! Thank you

Comment: why you are doing `*ngFor`?

Comment: @Abhishek I'm using it to retrieve the individual object inside the object for rows. For example,{1: {1:a}, {2:b}, 2: {1:c}, {2:d}} doing a *ngFor='let x of y' {{x.1}} should get it a and c right? Should I not do this?

Comment: i think it is complicated with mat table but if you try it normal table ease for you.

Comment: @Abhishek I can do it in a normal table, but I want to use it in a mat table so it matches the look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. Turns out it was `*matCellDef="let element">{{element.actualEPS}}`, where that's only referencing MatTableDataSource. So I used `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();` then

```js
  getEarning(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.svc.getEarningById(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.symbolEarnings = data;
      this.symbolEarningsDetail = this.symbolEarnings.earnings;
      this.dataSource.data = this.symbolEarningsDetail;
```